Given a singleton class injected via DI, what happens when multiple threads hit the singleton method
I have a very basic question:
Say I have below class which is registered as singleton, and a method. What happens when Create() is hit by multiple threads? Do they all the threads get access to this method at same time? If 10 threads hit this method, does 10 numbers variable get created and disposed off once the scope of method ends?
As this class doesn't have any class level properties, I assume it is thread safe?
// registration
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISingleton, SingletonTest>();

 public interface ISingleton
 {
     int Create(int number);
 }
 public class SingletonTest : ISingleton
 {
     public int Create(int number)
     {
         List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

         numbers.Add(number);
         return numbers.Count;
     }
 }


The numbers list will be created 10 times, once per call. It doesn't matter if they are all from the same thread, or split amongst any number of threads, then garbage collection (eventually) cleans up these lists.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316406/thread-safe-c-sharp-singleton-pattern

and when use it : https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/thread-safe-singleton-design-pattern/#:~:text=You%20should%20consider%20using%20the,accessed%20concurrently%20by%20multiple%20threads.

It sounds like you're unsure about what a singleton is and/or how multithreading works. Or, if you're good with those, then it must be DI. Where do you think you need help?


Do they all the threads get access to this method at same time?

Yes, there is no additional synchronisation techniques. Singleton is like create static member and access to it from multiple threads.
public static readonly ISingleton Instance = new SingletonTest();


If 10 threads hit this method, does 10 numbers variable get created and disposed off once the scope of method ends?

Yes, 10 numbers will be created, but not released after leaving this method. Releasing is done by runtime threads which execute Garbage Collector which releases not referenced allocated memory.

As this class doesn't have any class level properties, I assume it is thread safe?

Yes, it is thread safe. It will be also thread safe if you have properties, but not mutable, initialised once, for example in constructor.

So if 10 threads hit create, they get their own version of create (if that even makes sense)?
Say thread_1, hits create, and that generates  numbers. If thread_2 comes at same time, I assume it will never be able to access thread_1's  numbers?
If you have properties, I assume, it could have race condition issue, right? e.g One thread adds and item, and later wants to retrieve it, but another thread already taken that item

Each thread will have it's own numbers, numbers is variable in stack, each thread has it's own stack.

thank you so much!
If you have properties, I assume, it could have race condition issue, right? e.g One thread adds and item, and later wants to retrieve it, but another thread already taken that item - if you had properties, I assume race condition is possible?

Yes, if you have List property and threads is trying to add items to this thread. You will have problems.
