# Parallel For does NOT cause deadlock in static constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I was trying to add threading to a static class that I have and came across a bunch of problems. I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465961/potential-pitfalls-with-static-constructors-in-c-sharp) and the blog post that it links to and I think I understand what's going on. But I can't figure out why the Parallel For loop still works as in this example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

namespace ThreadingTest
{
    public static class TestClass
    {
        public static int AwesomeNum = 43; 

        static TestClass()
        {
            string[] x = { "deal", "witch", "panda"};

            //does not cause a deadlock? huh?
            Parallel.For(0, x.Length,  i =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x[i]); 
                });

            //results in a deadlock
            //Parallel.Invoke(writesomething, writesomethingelse); 

            //results in deadlock
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("there is a bear in my soup"); 
            }));

            thread.Start();
            thread.Join(); 
        }

        private static void writesomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("writing something"); 
        }

        private static void writesomethingelse()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("writing something else."); 
        }
    }
}


using System;

namespace ThreadingTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TestClass.AwesomeNum.ToString()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be interested in my recent series of articles about static constructor semantics. http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/06/static-constructors-part-one/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following *does* cause a deadlock:

```
Parallel.For(0, x.Length,  i => {
   Console.WriteLine(i); 
});
```

What's the difference?

The lambda expression I wrote above gets compiled as a method inside `TestClass`. So does the one you wrote in your `new Thread` example.

The lambda you wrote in the parallel expression, `i => Console.WriteLine(x[i])`, is compiled into a different, compiler-generated class because it captures `x`. So to execute it needs to statically initialize the closure class, but not `TestClass`.

So it's nothing to do with `Parallel` vs any other threading mechanism. It's just the difference between a lambda which requires the generation of a closure object and one which does not.

Note, I am describing the behavior of the current compiler. This behavior may be found in the relevant specifications, or it could be implementation-defined. I haven't looked.

Comment: The details of how closure classes are realized is called out as an implementation detail in the C# specification.