# How to run some code in a class at the time that it is defined?

Tags: c#, static

In Python, I can have the equivalent of C# static members:

```py
class MyClass:
  i = 0  # This is like a C# static member

print(MyClass.i)
```

gives output

```
0
```

But maybe my static member needs to be calculated somehow. I can do:

```py
class MyClass:
  i = 0
  i += 10

print(MyClass.i)
```

gives output

```
10
```

In practice, I'm writing a config class which needs to read a json file from disk, validate it, and then populate some static members. The closest thing to what I want to do in Python would look like:

```py
class GlobalConfig:
  with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
    config_dict = json.read(f)
  # Maybe do some validation here.
  i = config_dict["i"]
  a = config_dict["hello_world"]
```

Truth be told, I wouldn't really do this in Python, but I'm borrowing from C# in that everything needs to go in classes.

In practice in my C# code, I would have a `GlobalConfig` class in a `Config.cs` file and all my other files would have access to this.

But it seems I can't do anything other than declare/define members in the class body. How can I do the work of loading up and parsing my config file and have the result of that be accessible as static members to the rest of my program?

PS: I don't really want this to influence the answers I get in unless it has to, but FYI I am working with Unity.

Comment: you can have a static function that anyone can use. And even a static constructor, that does some global initialization so that your `Cnonfig`-class is allways fully initialized.

Comment: Oh a static constructor. Cool. I supposed this is it then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors

Comment: However I'd rather not go that path as it's pretty undeterministic when the static constructor is called - only that it *will* be called. You may have a private load-function that is called within all the others of not already done.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain are you saying that with a static constructor it's possible I try to access the static members before the constructor has run? And if so, wouldn't C# just try to call the static constructor first anyway?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437352/when-is-a-static-constructor-called-in-c for when it is called. It's a bit over oiut of scope for your question.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Then a static constructor sounds perfect because it's called "before any static members are referenced"

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465961/potential-pitfalls-with-static-constructors-in-c-sharp for potential pitfalls when using static constructor.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain thanks you've been super helpful. For the time being I'll accept Dmitry's answer as it's more direct, but you've provided a lot of value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `static` *constructor*?

```
public class MyClass { 
  private static int i = 0;

  private static int j;

  private static int loadJ(int value) {...}

  // Static constructor will be called before the first MyClass call
  static MyClass() {
    // If you want to compute anything with static you can do it here
    i += 10; 
    // you can call static methods here, address static fields and properties
    j = loadJ(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to static constrcutors is some lazy-loading approach. In essence you just initialize your class when it is used in any way calling the loading-function internally:

```
public class MyClass 
{ 
    static int i;
    private static int loadJ() 
    {
        i = ReadValueFromJson();
    }

    public static DoSomething()
    {
        // load if not yet done
        if(!loaded) 
            loadj();
        // do the actual work
    }
}
```

The advantage here is that you get more fine-grained controll about if or if not initialization should happen. Imagine some constant within your config-class that allways has the exact same value regardless of any initialization. The downsie is that you need to add this boilerplate to all the members that need loading.

Comment: Not sure if this would have any influence on your answer, but I don't want `i` and `j` to be private. I want theme to be accessed from anywhere else in the program **after** the setup has been done.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare You can make it a public property.

Comment: So is the idea then that I must call `DoSomething` in any place I want to use this? Just in case it hasn't been called already by some other thing?

Comment: @AlexanderSoare well, just within all the functions in your config-class. But I agree, that may become brittle when your config-class has dozenzs of members that all assume the class to be initialized in front.

Comment: Hm yeah I think I'm not seeing any issues with the static constructor so it seems like the more suitable approach.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare Just wait until your static constructor throws an exception... Fun times when that happens. My advice: NEVER allow an exception to be thrown from a static constructor.